# Why is the app crashing when the button in the array is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array with song titles, and I am adding a play button to each cell with a title, but when I click the play button it crashes, I get the array out of index error. Why is this error occurring? How do I fix it?

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    cell.textLabel?.text = ret[indexPath.row]

    let playButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    playButton.tag = indexPath.row
    let imageret = "playbutton"
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: imageret), forState: .Normal)
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(230, 20, 100, 100)
    playButton.addTarget(self,action: "playit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    for view: UIView in cell.contentView.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    cell.contentView.addSubview(playButton)

    return cell
}
```

Below is the code for playing the song based on which play button is clicked.

```
 func playit(sender: UIButton!){

    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") 

    let playButtonrow = sender.tag

    print(titleatcell[playButtonrow])



    if let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem{
    let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
    let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String



    print("now playing \(title!) \(artist!)")
    print("cell: \(playButtonrow) \(titleatcell[playButtonrow])")

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        query.whereKey("SongName", equalTo: ret[playButtonrow])
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) song(s).")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        print(object.objectId)

                        print(playButtonrow)
                        let object = object as PFObject
                        let parseAudio = object.valueForKey("SongFile") as! PFFile
                        let audioPath: String = parseAudio.url!
                        let urlParse: NSURL = NSURL(string: audioPath)!


                        player = AVPlayer(URL: urlParse)
                        player.volume = 1.0
                        //let timeInterval: NSTimeInterval = 10.0
                        //let timesArray = [NSValue(CMTime: CMTimeMake(Int64(timeInterval), 1))]
                        timeObserver = player.addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes([30.0], queue:nil) { () -> Void in
                            print("30s reached", terminator: "")
                            player.removeTimeObserver(timeObserver)
                            player.pause()
                        }
                        player.play()





                    }


                }

            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the crash report

Comment: Please post your full logcat output, you are asking why it crashes while not providing the log output, we are not wizards.

Comment: its seems like `titleatcell ` array is going out of bound, you can remove `titleatcell` as you are not using in your query.

Comment: I cannot screenshot at the moment but all the the crash console says is `fatal error: Array index out of range`

Comment: What line of code is this crashing on?

Answer (score 0):

"Fatal error: Array index out of range"

this error occurs when you try to access an array index that does not exist. maybe you're not getting parse the data, and when you click the button start , xcode tries to access a pointer that does not exist .... but we need more information to help you effectively